# Azure CDN - How to redirect from root domain to www? Some rules from Rules engine don't apply

Tags: azure

I created a static page using Azure Storage and CDN with Microsoft Standard pricing tier. I need to redirect user from `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` (with www), but my rules doesn't seem to work - only http to https redirection rule works so when I type `example.com` I'm redirected to `https://example.com`

That's my rules configuration:

[image]

That's domain records:
[image]

Both options are added in custom domains for this cdn:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that at first user is forwarded to `https://example.com` where there is no cert and privacy error appears and rules are not applied.
Rules could be changed to this:

[image]

so now user is forwarded from `example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, but if somebody will type `https://example.com` he will still see an error. Solution to this could be buy SSL cert, because Azure CDN doesn't allow CDN Managed SSL for apex domain.

Comment: I don't know why but removing the "And if request url begins with" line from the first rule removed a "Site does not allow http" access. When accessing (http://)www.mysite.com.

Answer (score -2):

### Goal

Redirect root/apex domain to WWW subdomain, using Azure CDN without buying/making your own cert.

### Can this be done?

Yes

### How?

Use below config, remember to use **Moved 301**, not "**Permanent Redirect 308**"

[image]