# How to redirect from non www. to www. in Azure using a blob storage static website?

Tags: azure, vue.js, nuxt.js, azure-blob-storage, namecheap

i'm trying to set up a redirect from https://animalcrossingportal.com to https://www.animalcrossingportal.com. The http -> https is already set up automatically with Azure so it's just non www. to www. required. The website is hosted in Azure using blob storage and a CDN with a static website, the domain is hosted on Namecheap and the site is built in VueJS/Nuxt. I've looked up Azure's documentation but it's either unhelpful or obsolete as a lot of their UI has recently been updated.

I've also spoken to their support who link documentation which is either outdated or for sites using App Services/Virtual Machines which I use neither. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done utilising anything mentioned above?

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your post if you are using it, but if not, take a look at Static Web Apps. Then follow this guide to set up the APEX domain https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apex-domain-external

Comment: Some info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73157129/8816585 Otherwise, this is probably also something to fix in your registrar (subdomain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Azure CDN to achieve this. Azure CDN can be used to in Front of Azure Storage. Azure CDN has a Rules Engine which you can use to define certain redirects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine

Comment: Would you know what condition the rule needs? I've put:
If 'Request URL' (condition), 'not contains' (operator), 'www.' (value), 'URL encode' (String transform)
Then action (response header), append (operator) header name (www.), header value (www.)

I basically need to append www. to the front of the URL if it's missed out

Comment: Have a look here. There is a good example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612833/azure-cdn-how-to-redirect-from-root-domain-to-www-some-rules-from-rules-engin

Comment: Thanks guys and @Julian, that worked a treat! Can confirm all redirects are working now